# Changing post depending upon where you're redirected from?

Tags: redirect, links

I want to create a post on my site in such a way that when a given user enters the first page (say, front), then some aspect of the "front" page changes (like picture shown, the name used to address etc) depending upon from which link the user enters. The links are other posts on my site. 
So for example, if 2 posts relink to the "front" page, I want it to be such that if the user enters the "front" page from 1st post, the user is addressed with a name and photo different from those he would've seen had he entered from the second post.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will require a bit of coding. The best way to do this with the use of query paramters. You'll need to add some query paramters to the end of each of your links. Then, on the landing page, check the query paramaters (which should have different values depending on which link you clicked) and display the content based on the vlaues in the query string.

Heres a resource to help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442180/getting-querystring-parameter-value-in-wordpress

Comment: I've searched the internet for quite a while now, but can't find how to do it. I found one thing that's closest to what I can use: making a form in previous links, get user's info like name etc, and then add that to the link of the landing page. But I can't find how to do it. Can you please help me out with this? Thanks.